Lifecycle of Azure function classes in Java
I struggle to find any information about the lifecycle of a Java class which contains Azure Functions.
Does each function execution use a new instance of the class? The reason I need to know is that I would like to save execution context specific objects (e.g. context.getLogger()) into instance variables to avoid passing them around.

new instance. Theoretically on premium with high load the instance might be reused. you can test it by initializing a variable if not null and by logging it

I agree with Paizo, on premium with high load the instance might be reused.

Azure Functions attempts to reuse instances of your function class at multiple invocations to optimize performance. in this case single instance of function class may handle multiple invocations.
context.getLogger() is specific to each function invocation. Storing this object as instance variables can be risky because the same instance of your function class might be reused for different invocations.
Instead of saving execution context specific objects like Logger as instance variables in your function class you can pass this object as method parameters to the specific methods like below example:

Function code:
public class TimerFunction {
    
    @FunctionName("TimerFunction")
    public void run(
        @TimerTrigger(name = "timerInfo", schedule = "0 */5 * * * *") String timerInfo,
        ExecutionContext context)
       {
        Logger logger = context.getLogger();

        // Your function logic here
        logger.info("Timer trigger function executed.");
       }
}


If you need to use  context.getLogger() within a method of your function class, pass Logger as a method parameter like mentioned in the above function code.

